# Fatal error LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED on registerForActivityResult

Tags: android, kotlin, registerforactivityresult

I have a simple empty activity that checks if permissions need to be requested. When `registerForActivityResult` is called, it crashes with the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner com.example.app.PermsRequester@41a30da is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.` From my research, I *think* I need to check if `savedInstanceState` is `null` and if so, create a new `fragment`? I'm not sure if that is the correct solution or how to implement. Below is the code:

```
class PermsRequester : AppCompatActivity() {
    requestPerms = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perms_requester)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.acceptButton).setOnClickListener { accepted() }
    }

    private fun accepted() {
        //There is code here to check if rationale dialog needs to be displayed
        //There is code here to build a mutable list of permissions that need to be requested and sets requestPerms = true

        if(requestPerms)
            requestPermissions()
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            //app crashes on the following line
            val requestMultiplePermissions = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
                 permissions -> permissions.entries.forEach {
                     //Handles permission result
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to `registerForActivityResult` before `onStart` of the Activity.

```kotlin
private lateinit var requestMultiplePermissionsLauncher: 
    ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    requestMultiplePermissionsLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
            permissions.entries.forEach {
                //Handles permission result
            }
        }
}

private fun accepted() {
    if(requestPerms) {
        val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        requestMultiplePermissionsLauncher.launch(permissions)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @KyzerSoze! I thought it _had_ to be registered outside of `onCreate()`. You saved me a lot of time! I appreciate it!

Comment: Same here, I was registering it in a lifecycle observer. thank you for the answer!